# prevent script from taking user to another page and alert the user regarding the change

Tags: php, alert

here is the script that i'm using

```
<?php
$saving = $_REQUEST['saving'];
if ($saving == 1){ 

$Aname = $_POST['Aname'];

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$last = $_POST['last']; 
$mob = $_POST['mob']; 
$ext = $_POST['ext']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$add = $_POST['add']; 
$com = $_POST['com']; 
$day = $_POST['day']; 
$text = $_POST['text'];
$date = date("M j, Y "); 

$data = "Date Sent: {$date}\n\nName: {$name} {$last}\nPhone : {$mob} ext: {$ext}\nCompany: {$com}\nAddress : {$add}\nE-mail : 

{$email}\nDay : {$day}\n\nNote :\n{$text}\n---------------------------------------\n";

$file = $Aname.'.txt';

file_put_contents ( $file, $data, FILE_APPEND ); 

}
?>
```

how can i prevent it from taking the user to another page after creation of the file, and also informing them that the file has been created?

Comment: above code wont take user anywhere .. it just reads the post data and writes to the file .. nothing more than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user is not going to another page after the creation of the file, the user is probably already going to another page when he / she hits the submit or save button.

To avoid that, you would have to use ajax:

- Use javascript to cancel the default submit button action;
- Use javascript / ajax to post to your current script;
- Have your script return a message / json ;
- Use javascript to show the message where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this code take you to another page?
Or theres something more to it that you havent printed?

Also you can show an alert by a simple javascript :

window.alert("You message goes here!");